# Autodesk Platform (getting started) oauth Problem --> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403

Tags: node.js, oauth, autodesk-forge

I tried to recreate the Simple Viewer on the Autodesk Platform page following the instructions in the Getting Started Guide (https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/). I went through the entire code and reached the end of the Data & Derivatives section (https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/data).
Now, when I try to access my server at "http://localhost:8080/api/models," I consistently receive the error message "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403."
Based on my research, this error suggests that I don't have sufficient permissions to access the page.
I'm not entirely sure what I've done wrong. I've even copied the entire code verbatim to ensure there are no typos. Additionally, I tried generating new credentials and verified that they match my .env credentials!
It's also important to note that I am the owner of the application being accessed.
I'm truly at a loss and would appreciate any assistance you can provide!

````
That's what my debug console displays.
```C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd start

> simpleviewer@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

run-script-pkg.js:64
Server listening on port 8080...
server.js:8
2
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403

[Error message in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds28d.png)
````

Answer (score 0):

Error code 403 typically indicates that you are authenticated (i.e., the platform knows who you are) but you are not granted access the specific resource that you're asking for.

One of the things to check on your side is the name of the bucket. Bucket names must be globally unique, so if you've used a common name like `test`, it's very likely that such a bucket already exists, and is owned by someone else. In that case, trying to access the bucket would result in the 403 error.